# enforce param same type as subclass

Tags: java

I am creating some mathematics (Java) classes and I need vectors of two, three and four dimensions (for processing 3D graphics). I decided to make one abstract superclass Vector, which implements all common behaviour, like scaling, addition, subtraction and dot products.

My question is: is there any way to express (with enforcement on compilation, not on runtime) that the second vector on which the dot product is executed must be of the same type as the subclass the dot product exists in (since they must have the same dimension)? (and is there a more efficient way to implement the vectors?) My code looks like this:

```
public abstract class Vector {

    protected float[] coordinates;

    protected Vector(float[] coordinates, int length) {
        this.coordinates = Arrays.copyOf(coordinates, length);
    }

    public float int dotproduct(/* Type? */ vector) {
        // do something
    }
}

class Vector2 extends Vector {
    // stuff
}

class Vector3 extends Vector {
    // stuff, including outer product
}
```

Comment: Are you using subclasses to represent vectors of different dimensions? That sounds like the wrong way to be going about this.

Comment: Well, there are some dimension-specific traits, like an outer product, right? It also helps enforcing the equality of dimensions on compile-time. On the other hand, I realized that it looks a bit weird and hence the question in parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your `Vector` class generic with a subtype of it. This is called an [F-bound type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) (or just recursive type):

```
public abstract class Vector<T extends Vector<T>> {

    protected float[] coordinates;

    protected Vector(float[] coordinates, int length) {
        this.coordinates = Arrays.copyOf(coordinates, length);
    }

    public float int dotproduct(T vector) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

And then:

```
class Vector2 extends Vector<Vector2> {
    // stuff
}

class Vector3 extends Vector<Vector3> {
    // stuff, including outer product
}
```

Comment: Ah, so this really is a thing? :) I already came across this, but I was not sure if it was legit. Thanks!

Comment: @TempestasLudi Totally legit, it's the same that it's done i.e. with the `Comparable` interface all across the Java API.